# How to obtain ROR and PRR of an adverse drug event using openFDA

Tags: openfda

I am writing a paper on adverse reaction mining, and I need to calculate ROR and PRR values of all adverse reactions of a drug. May I ask how to use openFDA to build query statements?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an "Event of Interest" (e.g. DIARRHOEA) and a "Product of Interest" (e.g. IBUPROFEN), then by following [this guide](https://allaboutpharmacovigilance.org/43-reporting-odds-ratio-ror/) you would need the following queries:

A: https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.medicinalproduct.exact:(%22IBUPROFEN%22)+AND+patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact:%22DIARRHOEA%22

B: https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.medicinalproduct.exact:(%22IBUPROFEN%22)+AND+(NOT+patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact:%22DIARRHOEA%22)

C: https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=(NOT+patient.drug.medicinalproduct.exact:(%22IBUPROFEN%22))+AND+patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact:%22DIARRHOEA%22

D: https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=(NOT+patient.drug.medicinalproduct.exact:(%22IBUPROFEN%22))+AND+(NOT+patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact:%22DIARRHOEA%22)

Hopefully this is a good start.